# Fading out of particles

Tags: particles, transparency

My question is not new, but I really can't get it. I watched a lot of videos with the same explanation, but it didn't work for me. I know that I'm loosing something, but I don't know what exactly.
Maybe someone can help me?

Here is my file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZsFvCpWQQ835Br-3mNrUZqDzbosKvue-

EDIT:
My nodes

[image]

Comment: Seems to work changing the mix shader... what is the issue exactly?

Comment: I want leaves to fade out over time.

Comment: So you just need to set keyframes. Select frame 1, set the fac to 0 and insert a keyframe on it. Then choose another frame in the timeline, set fac to 1 and insert a new keyframe.

Comment: will this help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67024UyCZ6A

Comment: particle info not supported in eevee

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do in the material of your particle object. heres a picture of my node setup [image]

If you want a tutorial showing how i made this, Blender Guru has a tutorial on making sparks.

hope this helps

EDIT: you can adjust the color ramp, to adjust how soon the particles fade out and how long it takes.

Here's how it works:

the particle info node takes into account the particle settings.  It then allows you to access them in the material with it's output connections.  In this example, I divided the age by the lifetime, which gives me a the age of the particle, but also takes into account how long the particle will live, so we can use that value to effect the material.  The color ramp provides the control you need to adjust how soon it fades out and how it does.  you could use this for even more complex effects, like repeated flashing if you wanted to.  the value on the left of the color ramp is the start of the particles life, while the value on the right of the color ramp is the end.  Using this as the factor between an emission node and a transparent, causes it to fade around the middle of it's lifetime, (due to the way my color ramp is set up).

you can use the same principle to change the color of the particle over lifetime, the strength of the emission over lifetime, and almost anything else.  I hope this edit has been useful, and that you can use it for more blends.

Comment: nice but maybe explain a bit how it works, especially the first nodes on the left

Comment: Alright, I edited it again, you were right, it's better to explain it so it can be used for other situations.

Comment: Thank you, but I really did it before asking a question/ I watched tutorial made by BlenderGuru and this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67024UyCZ6A , but I still didn't get any result.

I will edit my question and add my nodes.

Comment: Seeing your nodes, I think the way you have your color ramp set up, your particles would be solid for a short while, fade out for a long time, and then fade in again at the end, are you seeing this effect?

Comment: No. I tried to change in different ways, but nothing changed. I also tried to change in material settings blending mode, and it's also didn't work.
Particles just disappearing rapidly and thats all...

Maybe you can dowload my blend file, if it's not very hard for you?
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are using Cycles. Eevee doesn't support the particle info node.
Since you talked about "blend mode" in one of your comments, I'm inclined to think that you are using Eevee.

Compatibility explained here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/materials/nodes_support.html

As for fading:
[image]

Note that some leaves appear darker (more transparent) than others.

The divide node will ensure you obtain a value between 0 and 1. That value is exactly what's expected in input of the color ramp (0 is more black, 1 is more white), or the factor in the mix shader.

So you can also use the value directly in the factor of your mix shader, since it also expects a value between 0 and 1.

The colorramp does nothing in my example but you may tweak it for more or less transparency (whites down = more transparent).

Comment: Yes,  I tried to use both engines, and I have the same result...

Comment: Well, don't use Eevee in any case :)

Comment: Yes, I understood it) Thank you!

Comment: That said, I only ventured an explanation and a setup because it seems you still have issues with Millard's answer. I don't know whether you still need help.